# Ways to follow newly discovered vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, vulnerabilities

I happened to be in a situation where I am in charge for 100+ systems on top of my job as a programmer. Everything we run is Linux (Debian, Ubuntu, Centos) and gladly our sysadmin set everything with chef, so security patches can be applied quickly.

I would like to know how can I follow newly discovered vulnerabilities spending least amount of time.

As a programmer I am a fan of [Gemnasium](http://gemnasium.com), which does this kind of job for ruby gems I use in my projects.

Comment: Everyday i gather RSS feeds regarding, look into https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/ and http://lwn.net/Security/. If there is something I update systems using puppet. But I think you are looking for a more automated took.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be updated regarding your distribution your first stop should be the appropriate mailinglist and the advisory list from distribution

**Debian**

Mailinglist: https://www.debian.org/MailingLists/subscribe

Webpage: https://www.debian.org/security/

**CentOS**

Mailinglist: http://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo

Webpage: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/

**Ubuntu**

Maillist: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce

Webpage: http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/

Further you can keep an eye on http://nvd.nist.gov/ or https://cve.mitre.org/